# Apply style sheet to only a specific element trait

Tags: html, css

After doing a bit of googling I was unable to come up with an answer, so here's my question. Is there a way to specify a specific element trait, such as an id, inwhich an entire style sheet should be applied?

For example if I have a block of html like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="my_id">
            <!-- A bunch of elements here -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to specify that the rules contained in `./style.css` should only be applied to matching elements with in `#my_id`, similar to specifying `#my_id` before each rule in the style sheet.

I understand specifying `#my_id` before each rule will achieve this, but am wondering if there is a way to do it without the need to add bloat to the style sheet.

I'm working on a greasemonkey(userscript) script, which creates a 'container' element on a specific page in which it creates and places all other GUI elements required. I don't want my CSS interfering with the CSS on the page(such as accidentally over writing rules that already exist on the page), but don't want to add unnecessary bloat to my style sheet if it can be avoided since all rules are *only* to be applied to the 'wrapper' element and/or it's children.

Comment: do you mean, apply styles to elements within #my_id?

Comment: I do, but instead of specific rules. I want to know if there is a way to have my style sheet ONLY apply styles to elements within #my_id

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge this is not possible. As you stated you can prefix the rules with the ID, but this is not what you wanted to do.

I should say however, that you shouldn't have to specify a stylesheet for a single ID, because an ID is supposed to be unique in the context of the page. Furthermore, I find it bad practice to apply the same ID to elements which serve different purposes on different pages, because it can make writing common JavaScript pages quite confusing.

Comment: The reason I asked is because this is a Grease monkey script(a script stored and executed client side) on a 3rd party's page. The styles are not to be applied to multiple elements of the same id, but rather elements stored within an element with a specific id.

Comment: I gotcha. Again, I unfortunately don't believe that this is possible.

Comment: It should be possible if you  use ID's properly. You set an ID on the _unique_ element and target everything within it. Classes are meant for multiple elements.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks - I don't think that he has control over the IDs as they are on the 3rd party's page and therein lies the problem.

Comment: Aha ok then. Then pre-pending #id is the only way I guess.

Answer (score 1):

And this is one of the reasons people started to use [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). In SASS this would be as easy as just nesting all the css classes within the id class like so:

```
#my_id {
  // all styles without editing
  // Now all these styles are applied only if they fall
  // under the element with id "my_id".
}
```

**EDIT :** The other (ugly) option is to use an `iframe` instead of a div and load your child elements and stylesheet within it so that it is sandboxed as follows.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="my_id">
            <html>
                <head>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
                </head>
                <body>
                    <!-- A bunch of elements here -->
                </body>
            </html>
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

P.S: Don't forget to add the doctype. I have not added it in the example for simplicity.

Comment: Except SASS/SCSS is compiled down into CSS before browsers can use it. At which point my question becomes valid again...

Comment: Updated answer with an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

you can apply style to elements within #my_id using the > selector. example:

```
#my_id {
  /* some style for #my_id */
}

#my_id > p {
  /* this will style all p tags within #my_id */
}
```

Comment: As stated in the question, I know I can pre-pend the selecters to the beginning of my rules. I am asking if there is a way to do this without.

Comment: your question was not very clear. in any case, if you are trying to style items ONLY within #my_id, then you need to prepend #my_id, there is no other way. either that, or add style to the elements inline.